# Can we evaluate the any single decimal digit of pi even we skip the digit before it?

Tags: algorithms, pi, sequences-and-series

Can we evaluate any single decimal digit of pi even we skip to evaluate the digit before it?

Comment: This question is ill-defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; see for example [the Wikipedia page on calculating pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_pi#Digit_extraction_methods), particularly the "digit extraction" section (to which I linked).

Comment: Even the digit is in binary,it is awesome!

Comment: This answer should say "yes, if by 'digit' you mean bit". Note that OP asked for **decimal digit** and as far as I know, that's an unsolved problem...

Comment: @R..: If you'll see the Wikipedia page, Plouffe derived an algorithm to obtain the $n$th digit of $\pi$ in *arbitrary base*, subsequently improved by Bellard to work in $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Cool, I'd glanced at the linked section but just missed the very end.

Comment: For searching purposes: it's the so-called *spigot* algorithm.

Comment: An $O(n^2)$ algorithm to compute the $n$th digit could possibly cheat, by secretly computing *all* the previous digits as an intermediate step. For instance, imagine that it writes down the $k$th digit, given all previous ones, in $O(k)$ additional time. Do we know that this isn't the case with this particular (arbitrary base) algorithm?

Comment: @Srivatsan: The Wikipedia page includes a link to the paper by Bellard. You can check the description of the algorithm there.

Comment: There is currently no fast algorithm (record breaking) to obtain decimal digits.